# Insert row into database with PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I want to insert a row into a table using PreparedStatement. The table got 3 columns(int, String, String). The thing is that the int column is AUTO_INCREMENT, so I want to leave that variable empty and let the database do that job (It's an id). Haven't found out how to do this though!

It's an MySQL database.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That's relatively simple, just leave out the autoincrement column from the column list:

```
insert into mytbl(str1, str2) values (?, ?)
```

Prepare the statement, set the two parameters, and execute in non query mode.

Comment: Thanks, everyone pretty much said the same but your were first so u'll get the right :)

Comment: In MySQL, pass NULL to the ID column also make it AUTO_INCREMENT `insert into t (id, col1, col2) values (NULL, ?, ?)` or `insert into t (id, col1, col2) values (?, ?, ?)` with java code `stmt.setNull(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER)`

Comment: can we use this ? `insert into mytbl(str1, str2) values ('Example', ?)` and then `ps.setString(1,"String2")` or we have to use `ps.setString(2,"String2")`

Comment: @DeepSidhu1313 Since there's only one parameter, you call `setString(1,...)`, not 2.

Answer (score 19):

Just provide the String entries in your sql query string and the database will populate the auto_increment field:

```
String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO MyTable (StrCol1, StrCol2) VALUES (?, ?)";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertSQL);
preparedStatement.setString(1, "Val 1");
preparedStatement.setString(2, "Val 2");
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 5):

If the field is already autoincrement, it is enough to populate just the other two fields. Here an example

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO mytableName("
    + "fistStringColumnName,"
    + "secondStringColumnName) "
    +  "VALUES(?,?)";

try (PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {

    // Set the values
    pstmt.setString(1, "firstString");
    pstmt.setString(2, "secondString");

    // Insert 
    pstmt.executeUpdate();

} catch (SQLException e) {

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

}
```