# inserting java array values into mysql by using prepared statement

Tags: java, jdbc

Hi friends in my code I am receciving the values by using request.getParameterValues() from JSP page in the form of array and im passing it to getter setter from there im passing to DAO but i dont know how to insert the values of each arrary element into the  database by using prepared statement . my doubt is how to insert remarks,quantity,startTime, endTime for each iteration my code is

```
  Servlet Code : 

  String[] remarks = request.getParameterValues("txtRemarks");
  String[] quantity = request.getParameterValues("txtQty");
  String[] startHrs = request.getParameterValues("txtStartTime");
  String[] endHrs = request.getParameterValues("txtEndtime");

  getter setter :

  public String[] getremarks() {  
  return getremarks;  
  }  
  public void setremarks(String[] newremarks) {  
  remarks = newremarks;  
  } 

 UserDAO :


         String query = "insert into table(remarks,quantity,startTime,endTime) values (?,?,?,?) "
         currentCon = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
         ps = currentCon.prepareStatement(query);
         rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Try going through documentation - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: @NayanWadekar could you please suggest me some working examples please

Comment: It's already there, have you gone through that & tried something; if encountering issues, update post.

Comment: @NayanWadekar sorry i'm new to java so i dono how to do map entry

Comment: @NayanWadekar shall i mail my code to you ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert row into database with PreparedStatement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804906/insert-row-into-database-with-preparedstatement)

Answer (score 0):

Although I think you should update your application design, more specifically the way you are getting the data from servlet. 
There should be a bean with name e.g. `MyBean` to hold the data for each entity you will store into database not having separated arrays of attributes:

```
class MyBean {
  String remark;
  String quantity;
  String startTime; //You said it is a String but maybe should be a timestamp
  String endTime;

  //Getters & Setters
}
```

So back to your code now, and you should note that this is a wild guess since I can really figure out how you want the data to go under your tables:
 * Do you want to store an array of *remarks* in a single column?
 * Or those *remarks* stand each for a separate record?

Supposing that you are going for the second approach, your data access layer service can be as below:

```
public void insertMyEntity(String remark,
  String quantity,
  String startTime,
  String endTime) throws SQLException {

  Connection con = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
  PreparedStatement insertStatement = null;
  String insertString =
    "insert into YOUR_TABLE(remarks,quantity,startTime,endTime) values (?,?,?,?)";

  try {
    insertStatement = con.prepareStatement(insertString);
    insertStatement.setString(1, remark);
    insertStatement.setString(1, quantity);
    insertStatement.setString(1, startTime);// use setTimestamp() if it is a timestamp
    insertStatement.setString(1, endTime);
    insertStatement.executeUpdate();
  } catch (SQLException e ) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  } finally {
    if (insertStatement != null) {
      insertStatement.close();
    }
    if (con != null) {         
      con.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Then when you have retrieved your data from client request in your controller (`Servlet`), you can use a loop to iterate over them and insert to database:

```
public class MySservlet extends HttpServlet
{
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
  {
    ...
    String[] remarks = request.getParameterValues("txtRemarks");
    String[] quantity = request.getParameterValues("txtQty");
    String[] startHrs = request.getParameterValues("txtStartTime");
    String[] endHrs = request.getParameterValues("txtEndtime");

    for (int i = 0; i < remarks.length; i++)
    {
      insertMyEntity(remarks[i], quantity[i], startHrs[i], endHrs[i]);
    }
    response.sendRedirect("resourceuri");//replace the resource with servlet, jsp or html URL
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you but i want to redirect the page once it is inserted how that is possible within for loop for   each iteration

Comment: How does it come to redirect after each iteration? If you add the suggested line by @Selva, only the first statement will be inserted then the client will be redirected.

Comment: no i need to redirect the page once the entire iteration has been completed

Comment: So you have to move the redirect line out of the iteration, I will uppdate my answer and you can mark it as accepted and even upvote so it is eligible for future visitors ;)

Comment: Hi tmarwen, can I know if I can use getPost in this case for  MySservlet ?

Comment: Hey Karen, could you please be more explicit? Which `getPost` method do you need to use?

Answer (score 0):

tmarwen code will works fine, you just replace the `try` like below

```
try {
    insertStatement = con.prepareStatement(insertString);
    insertStatement.setString(1, remark);
    insertStatement.setString(1, quantity);
    insertStatement.setString(1, startTime);// use setTimestamp() if it is a timestamp
    insertStatement.setString(1, endTime);
    insertStatement.executeUpdate();
  } catch (SQLException e ) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  } finally {
    if (insertStatement != null) {
      insertStatement.close();
    } if (con != null) {         
      con.close();
    }
  }
response.sendRedirect("servlet/jsp");//Where ever you require to redirect
```

Comment: can i have your mail id please and myself also from coimbatore

Comment: @user3626977 First don't ask the code like this effort to [google](https://www.google.com/#q=preparedstatement+java+insert) it and sample for searching my link will facilitate you and if there any issues search relative answer to that if not post the question.

Comment: @user3626977 I don't mean to hurt you, you have mistaken, if search goes answer comes this is my thought..

Comment: @user3626977 How did you search for this solution? what are the keywords you have used to find the solution, my [SearchLink](https://www.google.com/#q=preparedstatement+java+insert) is here...