# Action button not working when inserting data into SQL DB - Java

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I'm trying to insert data into my SQL tables. I have a Jframe:

[image]

The purpose of the form is to input whatever is written on these text fields into the database.
My problem is that when I press *Send Request*, nothing happens.. Am I missing something?

This is my code for the *Send Request* button:

```
private void SendRequestActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = (Connection)
            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database","my-user","my-pass");
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

            //execute commands that collects
            //the text/items from  the fields and converts them to strings
            String MedRole = ofMedRoleComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String PtID = ofPatientIDField.getText();
            String Date = ofDateField.getText();
            String Time = ofTimeField.getText();
            String Purpose = ofPurposeComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();


            // sql query
            String insertOrdersDB = "INSERT INTO Orders ('PatientID','MedicalRole','Date','Time','Purpose') VALUES ("+MedRole+","+PtID+","+Date+","+Time+","+Purpose+")";

            // executing sql query
            stmt.executeUpdate(insertOrdersDB);

        }
        catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

In **e.printStackTrace();** is:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the 
right syntax to use near ''PatientID','MedicalRole','Date','Time','Purpose') VALUES (Nurse,7,2016-04-13,12' at line 1
```

I was thinking it was the date syntax, which is different from the SQL. So I changed it to match the SQL table format. But still got the same error.

Now I think it's regarding the Time ?

Comment: How is this method related to an `ActionListener` ? Also, print the stack trace of the Exception you might catch.

Comment: please, add e.printStrackTrace() into your catch-block so that you will get what error are you phasing if any then, and post it over here, we all help you to come out from this..!!

Comment: You should add stack tracing in your catch block. Probably a SQL Exception is thrown, but you cannot see it.

Comment: See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556)

Comment: Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: You really should be using [Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html). You're also ignoring the one piece of information which would tell you what the likely cause of the problem is. Add `e.printStackTrace();` to the body of your `catch` block

Comment: @Kranolabar can you please insert code for table creation? looks like you have wrong columns names

Comment: @LadislavDANKO Thanks for noticing that ! Yes, I changed the SQL query

Comment: I think that you shall follow @MadProgrammer advice and use PreparedStatement. It seems that you are trying to insert a Date as a String. Also you don't have to use ['] simple quote in the column names. Maybe this example helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804906/insert-row-into-database-with-preparedstatement

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I followed some of your comments and feedbacks. Thank you so much for that. I'm still learning Java and I know I've a long way to go.

But anyway, thanks to your guidance, I managed to get my Form to work.

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = (Connection)
        DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database","my-user","my-pass");    

        String sql = "INSERT INTO Orders (PatientID, MedicalRole, Date, Time, Purpose) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";    

        pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pstmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(ofPatientIDField.getText()));
        pstmt.setString(2, ofMedRoleComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
        pstmt.setObject(3, ofDateField.getValue());
        pstmt.setObject(4, ofTimeField.getText());
        pstmt.setString(5, ofPurposeComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString());

        pstmt.executeUpdate();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

So yes, I replaced this with my previous **try** and it worked !

Thank you for telling me to use *[Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)* :)
@MadProgrammer

Comment: Oh and e.printStackTrace() is a really good tip too ! Helped me figure out what I was missing